# How does Android know my password contains only numbers?

Tags: security, password, password-protection

My Android phone's unlock type is set to a password, but it only contains numbers for fast unlocking (I'm well aware that a PIN is an option, but this way presents more possibilities to an attacker). My phone's USB storage is encrypted so that I must enter my password on boot, and when I do, I am provided with a numerical-only keyboard. How does my phone know that my password only contains numbers? Does it store the password in plain text?

Answer (score 5):

Your password certainly shouldn't be being stored in plain text, although without reviewing the exact software your phone is running I can't rule the possibility out. More likely, when you set the password, it checked which characters are used and set a flag (in the plain-text portion of the system where the boot code and device unlock functionality live) indicating which keyboard type was most suitable. It probably *shouldn't* do that, but it could reasonably be described as a convenience feature.

Alternative explanation: are you 100% sure that, when you set your password, you did it in a way that allowed setting non-numeric characters? Maybe you have a PIN by accident. Try changing your password, and see what keyboard it gives you. If it's the full keyboard that you expect, that's an argument for the "sets a flag" theory. Try adding a single letter or symbol the the password and seeing if it changes the keyboard presented when unlocking.